# Cygwin Setup does not install gdb.exe

Tags: python, c, netbeans, gdb, cygwin

I'm trying to use NetBeans 8.1 with Cygwin to write, compile and debug a C program. I knew nothing about C when I started this, and somehow found my way to fixing all the compiler errors. But when it came time to debug there was no debugger!  Long story short, there's no gdb.exe in the Cygwin/bin directory and even a fresh install of Cygwin didn't produce one.

I tried another gcc compiler that did have gdb, but Netbeans won't use it.

I really don't know anything about debugging C in Netbeans with Cygwin. All I wanted to do was just bash my way through this one C program because I need to access a C library.

Alternatively, does anyone know if and how to run a C subroutine in python? (A vastly superior language to C/C++, in my opinion.)

I would be delighted to get access to this C library from either NetBeans or rewrite my access code in python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cygwin setup can install ~ 4000 packages.GDB is one of them.
Why do you think GDB should be installed by default ?

Please read:
https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

Comment: Oh, because I really don't know anything about Netbeans, Cygwin or C, as I stated in my original question. Thanks for the link, and I will try reinstalling Cygwin - with gdb - using this information. Since I have the entire C code to access this library written and it passes compiler muster, it would be nice if I could just finish that.

Answer (score 0):

(I wrote this before I saw matzeri's response. I still may try extending python to run code from the C library, but getting the C code I've already written to work would be vastly preferable.)

I have no idea what's going on with Cygwin's gdb, but after getting over my frustration I answered my alternative question. Turns out you can indeed call a C function from python. [Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html)

I'll try it tomorrow and I see caveats, but if python.org has a section on it, I'm betting it can be done.